# The eigenvectors of a general upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am searching for the eigenvectors of an upper $n\times n$ triangular matrix $U$ with distinct and non-zero entries. What I know is that the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $U$ and to determine $v_{\lambda_{i}}$ I took the simplest case that is for $n=2$, we can see that an upper triangular matrix has the first column of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as an eigenvector to $\lambda_{1}$ of $U$. Moreover, I believe $v_{\lambda_{2}}$ can be founded as a linear combination of $e_{2}$ and $e_{1}$. Using the basic form of the eigenvalue problem, I am able to derive the second eigenvector of $U$ as follow :
$$
U(e_{2}+\alpha e_{1})=u_{2,2}(e_{2}+\alpha e_{1})
$$
$$
u_{2,2}+u_{1,2}e_{1}+\gamma u_{1,1}e_{1}=u_{2,2}e_{2}+\gamma u_{2,2}e_{1}
$$
$$
u_{1,2}=\gamma(u_{2,2}-u_{1,1})
$$
assuming distinct eigenvalues $(u_{1,1}\neq u_{2,2})$ we get :
$$
v_{\lambda_{2}}=e_{2}+\frac{u_{1,2}}{u_{2,2}-u_{1,1}}e_{1}
$$
For the $j-1$ eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_{j-1}$, what I can see is that it must have its first $j-1$ entries as non-zero so I expect $v_{\lambda_{j-1}}$ to be formed as a linear combination of the past $j-2$ eigenvectors such that :
$$
v_{j-1}=e_{j-1}+\alpha_{1} v_{1}+\ldots+\alpha_{j-2}v_{j-2}
$$
I am not able to see what pattern the coeffecients $\{\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\ldots,\alpha_{j-1}\}$ have except for the simple case of $n=2$ therefore I hope someone can assist me in generalizing $U$ for its full size to determine the formula for the $j^{th}$ eigenvector

Comment: You are looking for a basis of eigenvectors, but you should realise that triangular matrices are not always diagonalisable. Therefore hoping of a _formula_ that will give you such a basis as a function of the matrix coefficients is unrealistic. Only if you allow for division by differences of diagonal entries, which means that the expression will be undefined in all non diagonalisable cases, then there is some possibility for (such limited) success.

Comment: If we assume that the entries are non-zero to ensure that the matrix is diagonalizable, can we extend as seen in the base case to a general formula? @MarcvanLeeuwen

Comment: distinct, not non-zero

Comment: Indeed, I will update my question to assert this @MarcvanLeeuwen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that the eigenvalues are the diagonal elements, Let's assume moreover that they are distinct. Reduce now to finding the kernel of an upper triangular $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with exactly one $0$ on the diagonal. Assume that the $k$-th diagonal element is $0$. Let $v$ a vector such that $A v = 0$. Then the components with index $k+1$ up to $n$ of $v$ are all $0$. Only the first $k$ components of $v$ may be non-zero. To determine then, consider the leading $k\times k$ block of $A$. The truncated (first $k$ components) $\bar v$ is orthogonal to the first $k-1$ rows of this block. Now, there is a formula to find a vector ortogonal to $k-1$ of the rows of a $k\times k$ matrix, it involves using algebraic complements ( similar to the vector product that is orthogonal to two vectors).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it serves as an interesting exercise

Comment: @Micho1999: You are welcome! Indeed, an interesting question.